# Using a conditional OR in a view query alter programmatically

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to use an conditional OR in my custom module.

```
hook_views_query_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query)
```

I get it to work with either one of these conditions set, but not together.

```
if (isset($query->alterTags['VIENAME'])) {
  $query->condition('draggableviews_structure.entity_id' , NULL, 'IS NULL');
  $query->condition('draggableviews_structure.view_name', 'view_display_name', '=');
}
```

How do I set an OR value between them, so if either is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `orConditionGroup()`:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('map');
  $group = $query->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('attributes.color', 'red')
    ->condition('attributes.color', 'green');
  $entity_ids = $query
    ->condition('attributes.building_type', 'bikeshed')
    ->condition($group)
    ->execute();
```

Example from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Query!QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3AorConditionGroup/8.2.x

Edit:

The question has a typo in the hook name, correct is

```
hook_query_views_alter(AlterableInterface $query)
```

which implements hook_query_TAG_alter() for a query tagged by Views.

Comment: I don't think this applies to hook_views_query_alter. $query is a Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql object. I'm using $query->setGroupOperator('OR') but it doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: @Aporie, thanks for the downvote. You are using a different hook. The question is about `hook_query_views_alter(AlterableInterface $query)`, you are using   `hook_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query)`. The hook names can easily be confused, but the hook parameters can't be,

Comment: Well, probably the downvote should also go to the question, which is super misleading. I got here from hook_views_query_alter google search (which is in the question) but then the parameter is Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query. It's nothing personal, I'm just trying to save time to other people passing by ... Maybe edit your answer and put at the top your EDIT or add the answer for hook_views_query_alter.